# Can phase term be removed in magnitude calculation

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, angle

To give the background of my question, I am studying Zernike moments and need to work with magnitude only. Since my understanding of polar and cartesian coordinates is limited, I am failing to understand what would be basic for a person of related field.

The complex Zernike polynomials be represented as $V_{nm}(x,y)$ in the cartesian coordinates. Equivalently in $\left(\rho, \theta\right)$ polar coordinates they can be decomposed into the product of a radial polynomial $R_{nm}(\rho)$ and a phase term depending on $\theta$. Thus:
$$
V_{nm}(x, y) = V_{nm}(\rho, \theta) = R_{nm}(\rho) e^{- \mathrm{j} m \theta}
$$

The moments can then be computed as:
$$
A_{nm} = \frac{n+1}{\pi}\sum_x \sum_y f(x,y) V_{nm}^{*}(\rho, \theta), \; x^2 + y^2 \leq 1
$$

I have no idea what the $*$ is :(
Since magnitude and phase collectively give the value, I need to confirm that if we are interested only in magnitude, can we remove the whole $e^{- \mathrm{j} m \theta}$ term. Conversely, can we replace $V_{nm}(\rho, \theta)$ with $R_{nm}(\rho)$ in the last equation?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $*$ means complex conjugate, in your case for $V_{nm}(\rho, \theta) = R_{nm}(\rho) e^{- \mathrm{j} m \theta}$ it is $V_{nm}^{*}(\rho, \theta) = R_{nm}(\rho) e^{\mathrm{j} m \theta}$.

Comment: Thanks! So the difference is of the minus sign as it is a conjugate.

Comment: No, you can't just ignore those terms. Say you have only two terms in the sum: $Ae^{-j\alpha}$ and $Ae^{+j\alpha}$. If you ignore the exponential part you get $2A$. If you add them correctly you get $2A\cos\alpha$. The magnitude of these two is generally not the same.

Comment: Thanks, should this not be answer rather than comment